# angularjs posting to php page: empty post array

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, post

I am relatively new to angular and following a simple tutorial on posting data to a php page from a form.  I am getting a successful callback and I can console.log my form data.  However I am getting an empty post array.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js"></script>


    <script>
        // Defining angularjs application.
        var postApp = angular.module('postApp', []);
        // Controller function and passing $http service and $scope var.
        postApp.controller('postController', function ($scope, $http) {
            // create a blank object to handle form data.
            $scope.user = {};
            // calling our submit function.
            $scope.submitForm = function () {
                // Posting data to php file
                $http({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: 'clone.php',
                        data: $scope.user, //forms user object
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                        }
                    })
                    .success(function (data) {
                        if (data.errors) {
                            // Showing errors.
                            $scope.errorName = data.errors.name;
                            $scope.errorUserName = data.errors.username;
                            $scope.errorEmail = data.errors.email;
                            console.log('failure');
                        } else {
                            $scope.message = data.message;
                            console.log('success');
                        }
                    });
            };
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="postApp" ng-controller="postController">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
            <div class="page-header">
                <h1>Post data using angularJS</h1>
            </div>
            <!-- FORM -->
            <form name="userForm" ng-submit="submitForm()">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name">
                    <span ng-show="errorName">{{errorName}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" ng-model="user.username">
                    <span ng-show="errorUserName">{{errorUserName}}</span>
                    <span ng-show="message">{{message}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email">
                    <span ng-show="errorEmail">{{errorEmail}}</span>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

```
    <?php
$errors = array();
$data = array();
// Getting posted data and decodeing json
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

// checking for blank values.
if (empty($_POST['name']))
  $errors['name'] = 'Name is required.';

if (empty($_POST['username']))
  $errors['username'] = 'Username is required.';

if (empty($_POST['email']))
  $errors['email'] = 'Email is required.';

if (!empty($errors)) {
  $data['errors']  = $errors;
} else {
  $data['message'] = 'Form data is going well';
}
// response back.
echo json_encode($data);

echo $_POST['username'];

?>
```

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) I don't think you can do `.success()` I think you have to do `.then(function(response))` and then you can access your data with `response.data`

Comment: shouldn't `Content-Type` be `application/json`?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Made both of these corrections.  Still getting the same result